# Product of cosets and coset of product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integers

I want to prove $\overline{ab} =\overline{a}\cdot\overline{b}$.  Here $\overline{a} $ and $\overline{b}$ are elements of $\Bbb Z_n$. I am really having a bad time to prove it. I needed it  to prove that $(\Bbb Z_n,\cdot)$ is a Semigroup.

My Try : 
$\overline{a}\cdot \overline{b} $ is a subset of $\overline{ab}$. But I can not prove the other way around. Can you please help me by giving a hint?

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prove it the other way around, because it's not true. For instance, $\overline n.\overline n$ as set operation in $\Bbb Z$ doesn't contain $n$ (as long as $|n|>1$). However, that doesn't matter because that's not how $\bar a.\bar b$ is defined in $\Bbb Z_n$.

In $\Bbb Z_n$, $\bar a.\bar b$ is *defined* as $\overline{ab}$. The only thing we have to do is what you've already done: show that the resulting congruence class doesn't depend on what representative we choose for $\bar a$ and $\bar b$. In other words, that the $\Bbb Z$-product $\bar a.\bar b$ is a subset of $\overline{ab}$.

Comment: I can not understand your counter example. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @cmi If we calculate $\bar n.\bar n$ as subsets of $\Bbb Z$, then that set is equal to $\{\ldots, -2n^2, -n^2, 0, n^2, 2n^2,\ldots\}$. But $\overline{n.n}$ is the set $\{-2n, -n, 0, n,2n, \ldots\}$. Those two sets are not the same, for instance because one contains $n$ and the other doesn't.

Comment: Yea I got it.... Can u please tell me then how will I prove the associative property of that group if $\overline{ab}$   $\neq$  $\overline{a}\cdot\overline{b}$

Comment: @cmi Show that $(\bar a.\bar b).\bar c = \overline{(ab)c}$ and $\bar a.(\bar b.\bar c) = \overline{a(bc)}$, then use that the integers are associative to show that $\overline{(ab)c} = \overline{a(bc)}$. The proof that multiplication is commutative follows the same idea: Put everything under a single line by definition of multiplication in $\Bbb Z_n$, then use the property you want (associativity or commutativity) from $\Bbb Z$ to finish the proof.

Comment: I got it.. thanks a lot.